# TFS Add FolderDiff Results to Changeset (Or Equivalent Functionality!)

Tags: version-control, scripting, command-line, tfs

I have setup a process to automatically generate scripts for our database objects and place them in a folder.  I manually added the folder to TFS.  I would like to automatically detect changes between TFS and my folder, create a changeset based on the differences, and then checkin the changeset.  The following command displays all the differences that need to be updated in TFS:

```
tf folderdiff . /r /i
```

This could also be written as the following:

```
tf folderdiff . /recursive /noprompt
```

This command correctly identifies all the files that need to be added (target), deleted (source), and updated (different).  However, this is only an information output and I really don't want to have to write code to scrape it and take actions based on it.  My suspicion is that there is some obvious command that I am missing that I should use to generate the correct changeset.  What code will automatically detect changes and add them to a changeset?

Once I add changes to the changeset, I'll run the below code to checkin the changeset:

```
tf checkin /comment:"Change automatically detected." /override:"Automated commandline checkin." /noprompt
```

Comment: Any thought of using database projects?

Comment: If I understand your suggestion database projects would require changing the workflow of the database users for making changes to the database.  I'm trying to implement a daily object version history that doesn't require users to change their workflow.  I did this successfully with Perforce as the source control system and now I need to do it with TFS.

Comment: Curious, what part of the workflow doesn't work? I'm talking about the new [Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193294.aspx) feature, not the old stuff.

Comment: These are analysts working in Management Studio or creating objects through Access Projects and the like.  They are running scripts and code that they inherited or wrote over years.  Tables are often created as SELECT ColumnA... INTO NewTableName FROM OldTableName.  These aren't programmers and I'm sure they would be allergic to Visual Studios.

Comment: Yeah, being able to read DDL is a prerequisite for using database projects at present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963) - it includes the `tfpt.exe` command line tool which includes the `online` command that will locate changes and pend the appropriate adds, edits or deletes.  You can then check in the resultant changeset.  It's as simple as:

```
tfpt online /adds /deletes
tf checkin
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy solution.  I thought the online option only detected changes if the files had been marked as writable instead of read-only.  I ultimated used the following code: tfpt online /adds /deletes /diffs /noprompt.  The /preview option helped work through some of the additional details.  Thank you very much!